# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET REST WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

Hello so i've made rest wcf and trying to get some object call is done and after it return list of object i get msg:

```
GET http://localhost/ESService/ESService.svc/GetExecutiveSummariesByBuyer?buyerId=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I've checked google there was some info to add this to webconfig:

```
 <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1234567" />
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
```

But still no luck same answer from server:
here is my datacontract

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ESContracts
{
[DataContract]
public class ExecutiveSummaries
{
    [DataMember] public int BuyerID;
    [DataMember] public DateTime CheckOutDate;
    [DataMember] public int CheckOutPerson;
    [DataMember] public DateTime CreateDate;
    [DataMember] public int CreatedBy;
    [DataMember] public int CustomerID;
    [DataMember] public bool Deleted;
    [DataMember] public int DeletedBy;
    [DataMember] public DateTime DeletedDate;
    [DataMember] public int ESStatusID;
    [DataMember] public int ID;
    [DataMember] public bool IsDecisionGroup;
    [DataMember] public bool IsWritingStyleFormal;
    [DataMember] public int ModifiedBy;
    [DataMember] public DateTime ModifiedDate;
    [DataMember] public string OpportunityTitle;
    [DataMember] public string Step2_Achievement;
    [DataMember] public int Step2_ComplianceID;
    [DataMember] public string Step2_Intention;
    [DataMember] public string Step2_SolutionAttribute;
}
}
```

--edit

i forgot to add interface definition:)

```
    [ServiceContract]
   public interface IESService{....


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetExecutiveSummariesByBuyer?buyerId={BuyerId}")]
    List<ExecutiveSummaries> GetExecutiveSummariesByBuyer(string BuyerId);
```

when i changed datetime to string it's working any ideas?

Comment: It may be because of many possible reasons why connection is getting reset. One of them could be exception in GetExecutiveSummariesByBuyer method. Could you please post code for GetExecutiveSummariesByBuyer method?

Comment: The problem is with DateTime format :) when i use it as string it workks when i pass whole DateTime object it reset connection...

Comment: I can confirm that, DateTime type is making my connection reset too.

Comment: Do you need solution for this?:)

Comment: In my case the same issue was caused by DateTime.MinValue '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' - fixed by using nullable DateTime - null instead of min value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample of Javascript code that do the case :)

```
String.prototype.FromWCFToJSONDate = function () {
   return new Date(parseInt(this.match(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)(?:.*)\)\//)[1]));
};
Date.prototype.JSONDateTOWCF = function () {
    var dt = this;
    var timestamp = dt.getTime();
    var date = '/Date(' + timestamp + '+0000)/'; // returns local time
    return date;
};
```